# Docker portainer + nginx + vpn

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, nginx

I have a docker install that is running portainer and nginx as a proxy
so subdomain.XXXXX.xyz redirects on port 80 to the port the Container is running in. this part is working correctly but I am having the worst time trying to get a vpn setup to protect some services that I dont want directly exposed to the internet

Target docker network layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLURK.jpg

in an ideal world I woul de able to create a vpn container assign ENV values to it and then attach it to the internet (red) and a private network (Light green) and have the srv4 and 5 only accessable when your connected to the vpn  with a vaild client without breaking the nginx proxy thats on the same box and shares the ip.

Any help would be greatly welcomed

Comment: What IP address do you get assigned when your VPN client connects and what is the IP address and port you are trying to reach?

Comment: the private network would be 
Subnet: 172.21.0.1/16 
for example srv4 would be hard set to 172.21.0.2
and srv4 is port 3000

have not got a VPN server going thats inside the docker only yet